# How to "break" sectioning/nesting?

Tags: sectioning

With the code below, baz is nested in bar. What I'd like to do is break this nesting, in other word make it look like a section as if there were no preceding chapters.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\chapter{bar}

% Sectioning break where 
% Everything that follows
% belongs to the document, not nested in preceding chapters

\section{baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to change the indentation in the table of contents, or should the appearance in the document itself also be different? If so, how would you want it to look? Which numbering should be used for the section?

Comment: latex has no concept of nesting for sections, if you don't number the section then it is not really contained or not contained in the preceding chapter,

Comment: I think changing the indentation in the toc would do the job.

Comment: I that case it's a duplicate, I think the question can be closed.

Comment: Why assume changing the indentation is the final word on this? Creating a line break in the toc would do the job too. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: what's the material that should “belong to the document” and not be “nested in the preceding chapter”?

Comment: For example, an index, bibliography...

Comment: Sometimes there is an irreducible vagueness to a question that can only be overcome with input from the experience of others. That said, I think the two suggested solutions will do the job. Thanks.